# Completely removing a package

Tags: apt, uninstall, gimp

I have recently corrupted my Gimp installation. When I try `apt-get remove gimp` it removes it. But when I try to reinstall it fresh from repository, it won't. It just installs it back from local package manager or repository.

I want Gimp completely get rid of, including all settings and configurations so my next install is all fresh like a first time install, so I hope my corrupt Gimp starts working again.

I've even tried using `apt-get purge gimp` but didn't work.

How is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: try `apt-get clean` or `apt-get autoclean` and then `apt-get update` all as sudo. Also have you checked that you the correct name for the gimp installation from a fresh repository?

Comment: The problem is likely not the `gimp` package, as you can't corrupt system software as a user. The problem is likely with your user-specific Gimp configuration. You can nuke your corrupted configuration by removing the `.gimp-2.8` directory in your home folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then you can reinstall gimp:

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

This should clear out the cache.

Comment: Success. But it didn't help my Gimp recover :( I asked a new solution here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/269676/restoring-default-fonts.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge gimp* && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get install gimp`

Comment: Only this solution solved my problems and it worked like a charm. If you were trying to install some newer version of gimp and you messed up the packages like me this is the only working solution to work. Thanks man!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: My pleasure buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then

```
sudo apt autoremove gimp
```

This should remove gimp from your destro and again try this

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Tested in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

do `sudo apt-get install gimp` and then `sudo apt-get autoremove`